# Reading string by string in a file's lines using a for loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, ifstream, istringstream

I need help with my C++ code, which reads data from an ASCII file and stores them into an `std::vector<double>`. The data are stored consecutively (as in the example below). For some reasons I want to substitute the `while(iss>>token)` with a `for` loop, like I did for the first `while` loop, when I use `getline()`.

Here is the code and below the ASCII file example.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

 std::ifstream file("example_file_ASCII");
 std::vector<double> tmp_table;
 std::string line;
 
 //while(std::getline(file, line)){
 for( string line; getline( file, line ); ){
   std::istringstream iss(line);
   std::string token;

   while ((iss >> token)){
     if (some conditions)
       tmp_table.push_back(std::stod(token));
     else (other conditions)
       //jump some lines for example
     }
  }
  

}
```

The `example_file_ASCII`:

```
1221  91.  94.  96.  98.  100.  102.  104.  106.  108.  110.  114.  118.  121.
 125.  127.  128.  131.  132.  134.  137.  140.  143.  147.  151.  155.  159.
 162.  166.  170.  173.  177.  180.  182.  186.  191.  194.  198.  202.  205.
 //the file continues
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the inner loop at all: `tmp_table = std::vector<double>(std::istream_iterator<double>(iss), std::istream_iterator<double>());`

Comment: Why do you want to replace a `while` loop with a `for` loop? What's the problem with `while`? BTW, no need to `getline` and to read into `string` `token` first, you can directly read into doubles from the file.

Comment: To amend my first comment, you should probably use `insert` instead: `tmp_table.insert(end(tmp_table), std::istream_iterator<double>(iss), std::istream_iterator<double>());`

Comment: ok, thanks. I simplified the code so much, I don't need just to append elemets to the tmp_table vector, I also need to put some conditions, so I think I need the inner loop. I show you modifying the thread.

Comment: Now it makes more sense to have that loop. And you could basically copy the first `for` loop if it's what you want: `for (std::string token; iss >> token; )`

Comment: Consider the base approach of first writing a function `vector<string> read_file(const string& filename)` and then another function `vector<double> to_double<const vector<string>& input)`. Not as efficient, but increases readability, can be tested separately and can be recycled in the future (for example is easier to adapt to parsing integers).